# SBNotificationHub.RegisterNativeAsync fails to return

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, azure-notificationhub

When calling `SBNotificationHub.RegisterNativeAsync`, sometimes it succeeds just fine, the registration is created, and notifications can be received. At other times, the callback of the method is never hit, and no registration is created. I added a timer to give some feedback on when this occurs. Since the callback is never called, I'm finding this difficult to debug.

The `UnregisterAllAsync` always completes successfully, and enters the callback.

This failure does not occur randomly. Specifically, when calling this for the initial registration on starting the app, it succeeds, when changing tags upon logout, it succeeds, when changing tags upon login, it fails. All of these use the same code, the only difference is the tags. I suspected the tags may be the culprit, but changing to a constant set of tags for all calls to this code did not change this behavior at all. I tried retrying the registration after 5 seconds (thus the timer) if there was no response, but that just results in the same failure every 5 seconds.

Similar behavior, by the way, when awaiting `RegisterNativeAsyncAsync`. The next line just never gets hit.

```
Hub.UnregisterAllAsync(DeviceToken, (error) =>
{
    if (error != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error calling Unregister: {0}", error.ToString());
        return;
    }

    bool callbackReached = false;
    Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(DeviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) => 
    {
        callbackReached = true;
        if (errorCallback != null)
            Console.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " + errorCallback.ToString());
        else
            Console.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync succeeded.");
    });

    new Timer((Object obj) =>
    {
        if (!callbackReached)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync failed to return after 5 seconds.");
        }
    },
    null,
    5000,
    0);
});
```

A solution would be great, of course, but just some more information about *why* the registration is failing, to give me some information to go on while debugging this, would be immensely helpful.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem with Xamarin.iOS.  Works on a fresh app start, but when I change tags.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I am also very curious if you ever found a fix, as I too am experiencing this issue. Over 2 years after initial detection... Is there something obvious we're doing wrong?